# How do you TypeScript the result of a promise?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
const counterAccount = this.accountsService.getFirestoreLinked('mas-accounts', this.selectedRelations[idx].accountId);
    counterAccount.then(result => {
        const state = result.mas.accountSettings.status;
    });
```

I need to set the value of the variable `state` to value of an element in a promise. The error message is "Property mas does not exist on type void."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to declare the type on **counterAccount**. You can declare type on **result**.

For Example:

```
// result.ts
export interface IResult {
 address: IAddress;
 birthdays: { text: string};
 mas: IMas;
}

interface IMas {
 accountSetting: {
 billing: boolean;
 gender: string;
 member: boolean;
 status: string;
}
}
```

Now declare the type on result

```
const counterAccount = this.accountsService.getFirestoreLinked('mas-accounts', this.selectedRelations[idx].accountId);
    counterAccount.then((result: IResult) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

As for your tslint not being happy about using result['mas'], it is because of a particular rule (i don't remember which one is it) in either tslint.ts or tsconfig.ts. You can remove that rule from the configuration but i would suggest not to do so as it exists there to follow a particular standard in the project.

Comment: Thank you. What I was missing was the (). It seems if you are declaring the type of an arrow function parameter you have to add the parentheses even if it is a single parameter.